# Refused API call in chrome extension while using in chat.openai.com

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chatgpt-plugin

I've been using manifest version 3.0 for my Google Chrome extension, and everything was working fine until about a week ago. Suddenly, my extension's API calls started getting refused, but they still work fine on other websites. The issue is only with "chat.openai.com."

This is a simple request for help

```
async function makeApiRequest() {
  var url = 'https://eno3nbzx5663j.x.pipedream.net/'; 
  fetch(url);
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
}
makeApiRequest()
```

This is my error screenshot

[image]

P.S: You can also test this in your browser console on the chat.openai.com website. Run the above code, and you will get the same error. Then try to run it in another website's browser console, and it will work fine.

Comment: Do the request in the internal extension script, [example](/a/55292071).